# Piping the contents of a file to ls

Tags: bash

I have a file called **"input.txt."** that contains one line:

```
/bin
```

I would like to make the contents of the file be the input of the command `ls`

I tried doing

```
cat input.txt | ls
```

but it doesn't output the list of files in the **/bin** directory

I also tried

```
ls < input.txt
```

to no avail.

Comment: `ls \`cat in.txt\``  would be simpler.

Comment: @Coldspeed It would also be wrong in general.

Comment: @chepner It works (on my mac). Is it a security issue?

Comment: Try `f=$'foo\tbar'; touch "$f"; echo "$f" > input.txt; ls $(cat input.txt)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are looking for the `xargs` (*transpose arguments*) command.

```
xargs ls < input.txt
```

You say you want `/bin` to be the "input" to `ls`, but that's not correct; `ls` doesn't do anything with its input. Instead, you want `/bin` to be passed as a command-line *argument* to `ls`, as if you had typed `ls /bin`.

Input and arguments are completely different things; feeding text to a command as input is not the same as supplying that text as an argument. The difference can be blurred by the fact that many commands, such as `cat`, will operate on either their input or their arguments (or both) – but even there, we find an important distinction: what they actually operate on is the *content of files* whose *names* are passed as arguments.

The `xargs` command was specifically designed to transform between those two things: it interprets its input as a whitespace-separated list of command-line arguments to pass to some other command. That other command is supplied to `xargs` as *its* command-line argument(s), in this case `ls`.

Thanks to the input redirection provided by the shell via `<`, the arguments `xargs` supplies to `ls` here come from the `input.txt` file.

There are other ways of accomplishing the same thing; for instance, as long as `input.txt` does not have so many files in it that they won't fit in a single command line, you can just do this:

```
ls $(< input.txt)
```

Both the above command and the `xargs` version will treat any spaces in the `input.txt` file as separating filenames, so if you have filenames containing space characters, you'll have to do more work to interpret the file properly. Also, note that if any of the filenames contain wildcard/"glob" characters like `?` or `*` or `[`...`]`, the `$(<`...`)` version will expand them as wildcard patterns, while `xargs` will not.

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks for pointing out the difference between input and command line arguments.

Comment: `ls $(< input.txt)` has so many exceptions, it's not even worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

`ls` takes the filenames from its command line, not its standard input, which `| ls` and `ls < file` would use.

If you have only one file listed in `input.txt` and the filename doesn't contain trailing newlines, it's enough to use (note quotes):

```
ls "$(cat input.txt)"
```

Or in almost all but plain POSIX shell:

```
ls "$(< input.txt)"
```

If there are many filenames in the file, you'd want to use `xargs`, but to deal with whitespace in the names, use `-d "\n"` (with GNU xargs) to take each line as a filename.

```
xargs -d "\n" ls < input.txt
```

Or, if you need to handle filenames with newlines, you can separate them using NUL bytes in the input, and use

```
xargs -0 ls < input.txt
```

(This also works even if there's only one filename.)

Answer (score 1):

Try xargs

```
cat file | xargs ls
```

Ohhh man, I have to put this to get 30 characters long ;)

Comment: This is less efficient than the version without `cat` (where `xargs` reads directly from the input file, rather than from a FIFO connected to a separate program reading from the input file).